How to modify PowerShell command length limit on Windows runner?
I am building a Make project with C and C++ files using Make for Windows as the make.exe and a gcc for arm toolchain.
When it comes time to link, the resultant command to gcc and the linker is a little over 12k chars long due to the number of object files and their paths.
The PowerShell in the Windows server VM used by GitHub Actions truncates my long linker command input.
Is there a way to configure the Windows server host in GitHub Actions to have its PowerShell accept larger input strings?
Tests I’ve run:

If I build it on a Windows 11 desktop and PowerShell calling Make for Windows, it builds fine.
If I build this on an Ubuntu hosted runner and its built in make with my gcc toolchain, it builds fine.
But, if I build it on a windows-latest runner in GitHub Actions, specifying PowerShell and calling Make for Windows, it doesn't build and it's clear that the command is being truncated.

Exact same makefile in all three cases.
